# How is the DTO objects transferred from client to server in spring-struts web application without implementing serializable

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, serialization, struts

I have a web application developed using Spring - Struts framework deployed in Tomcat 8 server. The application is hosted in only one server.

The application code is layered like

> Action |  BPO |  DAO | DTO | EntityObject

Only few DTO classes `implements Serializable` interface where those DTO objects are being written into file using ehcache for caching state.

Do we actually need to `implement Serializable` interface for all the DTO classes?

With reference to the below link it says not necessary to implement Serializable to all the DTO classes.

[DTO implementation of Serializable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833473/dto-implementation-of-serializable-interface)

If so how does the DTO object gets transferred from client side to server side without serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Serializable` is used by `java.io` and it's needed if you want to keep the objects in session. Some other frameworks is using `Serializable` behind the scene to perform serialization. If you don't know where the object is serialized using [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) you better add this interface to DTOs.

The client-side might use other [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) like JSON, XML, etc., but it doesn't affect the processes running serialization on server-side and it should be handled separately by your code or some other framework like Struts or Spring, doesn't matter.